# Java PreparedStatement and ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE: how do I know whether row was inserted or updated?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, database, jdbc

Having following code, how do I know if the execute() method resulted in insert or in update?:

```
Connection c = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionString);

PreparedStatement st = c.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO `table`(`field1`) VALUES (?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id=LAST_INSERT_ID(id);");

st.setString(1,"some value");
st.execute();
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Consider the following MySQL test table:

```
CREATE TABLE `customers` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `email` (`email`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

with existing sample data as follows:

```
id  name            email
--  --------------  ----------------
 1  Loblaw, Bob     bob@example.com
 2  Thompson, Gord  gord@example.com
```

With the default connection setting `compensateOnDuplicateKeyUpdateCounts=false` (described [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html)) the following Java code

```java
PreparedStatement ps = dbConnection.prepareStatement(
        "INSERT INTO customers (name, email) " +
        "VALUES (?, ?) " +
        "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE " +
            "name = VALUES(name), " +
            "id = LAST_INSERT_ID(id)");
ps.setString(1, "McMack, Mike");
ps.setString(2, "mike@example.com");
int euReturnValue = ps.executeUpdate();
System.out.printf("executeUpdate returned %d%n", euReturnValue);
Statement s = dbConnection.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = s.executeQuery("SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() AS n");
rs.next();
int affectedId = rs.getInt(1);
if (euReturnValue == 1) {
    System.out.printf("    => A new row was inserted: id=%d%n", affectedId);
}
else {
    System.out.printf("    => An existing row was updated: id=%d%n", affectedId);
}
```

produces the following console output

```
executeUpdate returned 1
    => A new row was inserted: id=3
```

Now run the same code again with the parameter values

```java
ps.setString(1, "Loblaw, Robert");
ps.setString(2, "bob@example.com");
```

and the console output is

```
executeUpdate returned 2
    => An existing row was updated: id=1
```

This demonstrates that `.executeUpdate` really can return 2 if the unique index causes an existing row to be updated. If you require further assistance with your *actual* test code then you should edit your question to include it.

### Edit

Further testing reveals that `.executeUpdate` will return 1 if

1. the attempted INSERT is aborted because it would result in a duplicate UNIQUE key value, **and**
2. the specified ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE changes *do not actually modify any values in the existing row*.

This can be confirmed by running the above test code twice in a row with the exact same parameter values. Note that the `UPDATE ... id = LAST_INSERT_ID(id)` "trick" does ensure that the correct `id` value is returned.

That probably explains OP's test results if the only value being inserted was the UNIQUE key value.

Comment: Wow, thanks for extensive explanation! So, adding some assignment like 'name = VALUES(name)' to the query makes executeUpdate() return 2 on update? I will try to do that. Could you elaborate on why SELECT_LAST_INSERT_ID() does not ensure correct id value returned? Thanks again.

Comment: @ed22 **(1)** re: "So, adding some assignment like 'name = VALUES(name)' to the query makes executeUpdate() return 2 on update?" - Not necessarily. In order for `executeUpdate` to consistently return 2 on update you need to ensure that the UPDATE actually *changes* something. One obvious candidate would be a `lastUpdated` column to hold the date/time of the most recent change (insert or update). **(2)** As I said, the `SELECT_LAST_INSERT_ID()` function *does* work even if `executeUpdate` returns 1 on update, so that is not really an issue.

Comment: @GordThompson are you sure this is correct? the documents say that executeUpdate will return the number of rows that were changed, thus returning 1 when a new row is inserted or updated with a change, and 0 if it was a duplicate and nothing was changed, or say 7 if 7 rows were inserted or 4 inserted and 3 modified for example.

Comment: @Chiquis I am sure that my answer accurately described the results of the actual tests I performed. Which "documents" are you referring to: the JDBC documentation for `executeUpdate`, or the specific documentation for MySQL Connector/J?

Comment: @GordThompson im refering to this one http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#executeUpdate()  which says "either (1) the row count for SQL Data Manipulation Language (DML) statements or (2) 0 for SQL statements that return nothing"

Comment: @GordThompson by the way i posted my own question about this here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29702595/what-does-the-java-mysql-executeupdate-returns-for-insert-on-on-duplicate-key because I have also seen the behavior you describe in other answers, but also seen the one i describe in yet, other answers and forums. So confusing imo...

Comment: @Chiquis The Java docs are saying what the JDBC driver *should* do, but there are lots of cases where the actual behaviour of a JDBC driver may be somewhat different. In this case MySQL Connector/J returns slightly different results, at least for the default connection settings. There is a `compensateOnDuplicateKeyUpdateCounts` configuration property described [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html) that sounds like it might produce results closer to what you expect if it is enabled (by default it isn't).

Answer (score 2):

Use [executeUpdate](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeUpdate%28java.lang.String%29) instead as it returns an `int` row count.

**UPDATE 1**: According to the [MySQL INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html):

> With ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE, the affected-rows value per row is 1 if
>   the row is inserted as a new row, and 2 if an existing row is updated.

**UPDATE 2**: `INSERT IGNORE` may also be an [option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/548541/insert-ignore-vs-insert-on-duplicate-key-update):

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO `table`(`field1`) VALUES (?)
```

`executeUpdate` should return 1 when a new row is inserted and 0 when there is a duplicate.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it does not do it for me. It returns 1 no matter if an insert or update was performed. What I need to know is if the operation performed was insert or was it update (I need to know which one).

Comment: I believe MySQL will use the return code to inform you if an insert (returns 1) or update (returns 2) occurred: 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Comment: I'm not sure why the affected rows count being returned is the same regardless of whether insert or update occurred, I don't have a MySQL server at hand to test with at the moment.

Comment: @ed22 - This answer is correct. For `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY` queries `.executeUpdate()` returns 1 if a new row is inserted and it returns 2 if an existing row is updated. The sample code in your question could be misleading because if the row already exists then there is really nothing else to change so `.executeUpdate()` may return an unexpected value. If you can create a sample query that better illustrates your issue then please edit your question to include it.

Comment: I have done some testing and executeUpdate() always returns 1 (no mater which part of my query was run). execute() always returns false with getUpdateCount() always returning 1. Maybe it works that way only for this particular query which updates last insert id no mater which operation took place (insert or update). I guess my only option is to run SELECT (to check if row exists) and then INSERT. These are two queries instead of one, but I would know if row would be updated or not. I just hoped it could be don in one query.

Comment: I'm not sure what the return value behavior would be for `UPDATE id=LAST_INSERT_ID(id)` if on a duplicate the primary key is updated. Any luck with `INSERT IGNORE`?

Comment: INSERT IGNORE does not update the last insert id when duplicate is found so it is not an option for me either...

Comment: Ok, I wasn't aware that you also want the id to increase even in the case of duplicate. Sounds like you may need more than one statement or a stored procedure

Comment: Actually, I believe that the `LAST_INSERT_ID()` "trick" is simply a way of ensuring that `LAST_INSERT_ID()` returns the `id` value of the record affected, even if it was an existing row (and no INSERT was actually performed). See the example in my answer for details.